# Почему ничего не происходит после нажатия на иноайн кнопку покупка?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
import asyncio 
 
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F 
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart 
from aiogram.types import Message 
 
import os 
import logging 
 
import keyboards 
 
#token 
bot = Bot('') 
dp = Dispatcher() 
 
 
 
@dp.message(Command("start")) 
async def start(message: Message): 
    await message.answer('Привет', reply_markup=keyboards.main_kb) 
 
@dp.message() 
async def echo(message: Message): 
    msg = message.text.lower() 
 
    if msg == 'помощь': 
        await message.answer('Моя контактная информация:', reply_markup=keyboards.links_kb) 
    elif msg == 'покупка': 
        await message.answer("сборник", 
                             reply_markup=keyboards.pof_kb) 
 
 
async def main(): 
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True) 
    await dp.start_polling(bot) 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Добавьте код keyboards.py, может быть проблема там.